# Pressure above = below?

Tags: pressure

Basic question:
Lets assume we have an object (cuboid) in the air, with area A, width w at height h. Is the pressure from above always equal to pressure from below at that object or is the pressure equal if the width w is infinitely small?

[image]

Comment: Is this object in a medium? If so, what? What shape is this object? This question is lacking much information. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @Drjh I have added an image to try to explain what I mean

Comment: So as you see in the two answers below, if the height difference is infinitely small then the pressure *difference* $\Delta P = \rho g \Delta h = \rho \times g \times 0 = 0$ is infinitely small.

Answer (score 1):

For a fluid with a constant density $\rho$ in a constant gravitational field, the difference in pressure between two points is given by $\Delta P=\rho gh$, where $g$ is acceleration due to gravity and $h$ is the height difference between the two points. Therefore, pressure at lower heights is always larger than the pressure at larger heights. This is because the lower you are the more fluid from above is pushing on a given surface.

If the change in height is infinitesimal then we just have $\text dP=\rho g\,\text dh$.

Answer (score 1):

The atmospheric pressure on Earth is around 14.7 pounds per square inch at sea level. This pressure lowers with increasing altitude. So the air pressure above a real object will be lower than the air pressure below it. The pressure difference will depend on the height of the object.